# How to broadcast set operation on array of sets in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to perform set operations between a given set `y` and all items in some array of sets `X` as follows:

```
X=Array{Set}([Set([1,2,1]), Set([4,6,8 ]), Set([4,5])]) 
y=Set{Int16}([2,8,4])
z=broadcast(intersect, y, X)

println(z)
```

Which gives me empty sets, instead of sets with the singletons in `y`, for my example.

Comment: Writing `Array{Set}(...)` is not a good idea in general. This turns the array into a vector with an abstract element type. `[Set([1,2,1]), Set([4,6,8 ]), Set([4,5])]` has type `Array{Set{Int64},1}`, but you turn that into an abstract eltype `Array{Set,1}`. This is likely to harm performance.

Comment: @DNF, thanks for your comment. I'm new to Julia, so I'd be grateful if you can recommend an alternative efficient approach.

Comment: Just write `X = [Set([1,2,1]), Set([4,6,8 ]), Set([4,5])]`, and let Julia figure out the types. It is also slightly better to write `Set(Int16[2,8,4])` than `Set{Int16}([2,8,4])` because the latter first creates a vector of `Int64` which then is turned into `Int16`, while the former directly creates `Int16`s. But I wonder why you are using `Int16` here.

Comment: Thanks @DNF. There is no reason to use Int16, I only tried to be correct by specifying a type, but I'm now aware of some extra details thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to protect `y` from being iterated over. Normally you would get an error but unfortunately `y` has three elements as well as vector `X`. Let us create a bigger vector then so see the problem:

```
julia> X=Array{Set}([Set([1,2,1]), Set([4,6,8 ]), Set([4,5]), Set([7])])
4-element Array{Set,1}:
 Set([2, 1])
 Set([4, 8, 6])
 Set([4, 5])
 Set([7])

julia> y=Set{Int16}([2,8,4])
Set{Int16} with 3 elements:
  4
  2
  8

julia> z=broadcast(intersect, y, X)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 3 and 4")
```

How to solve it - wrap `y` in a 0-dimensional container with `Ref(y)` like this:

```
julia> z=broadcast(intersect, Ref(y), X)
4-element Array{Set{Int16},1}:
 Set([2])
 Set([4, 8])
 Set([4])
 Set()
```

or equivalently just write:

```
julia> z=intersect.(Ref(y), X)
4-element Array{Set{Int16},1}:
 Set([2])
 Set([4, 8])
 Set([4])
 Set()
```

Comment: Thanks @Bogumil Kaminski, that solved my question.